# Jmeter - Inline evaluation error in Beanshell Assertion

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I am getting this error, and cannot figure out what wrong I am doing:

```
Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Set; import java.util.Map; import java.util.List;  try { //   Map . . . '' Encountered "String" at line 17, column 9.
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;

try
{
//  Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

//  map = vars.getObject("headerMap");
    boolean isHeaderValid = false;
    
//  String apiKeySent = "${x_api_key}"
//  String clientIdSent = "${X_IBM_Client_id}"
//  String clientSecretSent = "${X_IBM_Client_Secret}"

    String apiKeySent = vars.get("x_api_key")
    String clientIdSent = vars.get("X_Client_id")
    String clientSecretSent = vars.get("X_Client_Secret")

    log.info("apiKeySent: " + vars.get("x_api_key"))
    log.info("clientIdSent: " + vars.get("X_Client_id"))
    log.info("clientSecretSent: " + vars.get("X_Client_Secret"))
    
    if(apiKeySent != "")
    {
        apiKeyRec = vars.get("apiKeyRec")
        isHeaderValid = apiKeySent.equals(apiKeyRec)
    }
    Failure = isHeaderValid
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    log.debug("Error in verification: ",e)
}
```

Could anyone please help me in figuring this out? Have been stuck at this for ages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeanShell script error: bsh.ParseException: Parse error at line 126, column 23. Encountered: ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66775728/beanshell-script-error-bsh-parseexception-parse-error-at-line-126-column-23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to add semicolons like this

   ```
   import java.util.Set;
   import java.util.Map;
   import java.util.List;

   try
   {
   //  Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

   //  map = vars.getObject("headerMap");
       boolean isHeaderValid = false;

   //  String apiKeySent = "${x_api_key}"
   //  String clientIdSent = "${X_IBM_Client_id}"
   //  String clientSecretSent = "${X_IBM_Client_Secret}"

       String apiKeySent = vars.get("x_api_key");
       String clientIdSent = vars.get("X_Client_id");
       String clientSecretSent = vars.get("X_Client_Secret");

       log.info("apiKeySent: " + vars.get("x_api_key"));
       log.info("clientIdSent: " + vars.get("X_Client_id"));
       log.info("clientSecretSent: " + vars.get("X_Client_Secret"));

       if(apiKeySent != "")
       {
           apiKeyRec = vars.get("apiKeyRec");
           isHeaderValid = apiKeySent.equals(apiKeyRec);
       }
       Failure = isHeaderValid;
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       log.debug("Error in verification: ",e);
   }
   ```
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion and Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)
3. Your script can be simplified to

   ```
   AssertionResult.setFailure(vars.get('x_api_key') == vars.get('apiKeyRec'))
   ```
4. And you don't even need any scripting for comparing 2 variables, it can be done using "normal" [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

   [image]

Comment: Adding semicolons worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, thank you for the suggesting the best practices.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are forgetting to end all of your statements with semicolons from line 12 on.  Add semicolons and let me know how that works!